# Algorithm for incrementing a String in a non-obvious manner

Tags: java, string, algorithm, random

I want to create random-looking 5 or 6 character alpha-numeric strings, something like:

```
Vg78KY
```

Creating (pseudo-)random Strings has been answered, but I am wondering if there is an algorithm for **incrementing** a String in a non-obvious manner. A simple increment of the above String might yield:

```
Vg78KZ
```

But I don't want this next String to be guessable, I want it to look completely different. Of course, successive increments should not yield a previous result as each should be unique.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: how is "incrementing a String in a non-obvious manner" different than generating pseudo-random Strings?

Comment: @matt b - I grant you it's a fine distinction. I am hoping to avoid having to check for the existence of a generated String, which whilst unlikely is possible, so you're gonna have to do this check. Plus I thought it an interesting problem which might have some application beyond my basic needs :)

Comment: Easy, quit being so obvious when you do it.

Comment: @Richard - so the only difference is that "incrementing" won't return a String that has already been produced?

Comment: @matt b - yes, it is completely equivalent. However I am/was assuming that a GUID would have to be longer than 5 or 6 characters.

Comment: I can't think of the obvious way to increment a String.

Comment: Would the following approach fulfill your needs: use the original string as seed (maybe its hashcode) for the PRNG (your original one or any other) to generate the "incremented" string.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

An easy approach that avoids the need for lookup tables would be:

- Increment an integer normally
- Permute the bits in a non-obvious way (a fixed permutation is probably fine, but if you want something more sophisticated you could use something like [George Marsaglia's XORShift algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) that produces a psuedorandom sequence of integers that only repeats after a very long cycle)
- Convert to [Base64 encoded strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Comment: +1, and would give you +10 for the Xorshift reference, thanks!

Comment: I added the first 50 numbers on wiki :)

Comment: you could even use an unusual base for your encoding like base 59... or 42.  There is nothing that says you must you one of the standard base encodings.

Comment: Note that the linked XORShift algorithm works with a 128-bit state and has only a 32-bit output. There is no guarantee that it won't give you collisions by outputting the same 32-bit int with a frequency much less than its full cycle.

Answer (score 3):

If we assume there must be a 1:1 mapping from "sequence number" to "random-looking string", then the truncated hash approach will not work as there is no guarantee that the truncated hash won't be subject to collisions.

I'd do something like this:

- Take the next integer in sequence.
- Xor with a fixed number.
- Permute the bits.
- Encode the number using Base64, Base36, or whatever.

Note that this will be subject to easy analysis by a determined attacker with access to a sufficiently large set of sequence numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't have to be bullet-proof, reasonably hard (or even fairly hard) is fine.

Comment: @RichardH: The hardness will depend on the "permute the bits" step. For an input integer of N bits, your best bet there is probably to find a good PRNG that has an N-bit internal state and a period of 2**N-1. Use the input integer as the PRNG's internal state, run the algorithm a number of times, and then use the new internal state as the output to be encoded as your string.

Answer (score 2):

What **exactly** do you mean by increment? If you just want some values that is the result of the original value, the you can use a hash code (possibly a cryptographic hash). Then simply encode it a way that uses the characters you want to use (for example Base64 or something similar) and cut it off at the number of characters you want.

This is a one-way operation, however. That means that you can easily get successor of a value, but can't easily get the predecessor.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.UUID;
public class RandomStringUUID {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();

        System.out.println("Random UUID String = " + randomUUIDString);
        System.out.println("UUID version       = " + uuid.version());
        System.out.println("UUID variant       = " + uuid.variant());

    }
}
```

If you want to generate collision safe strings just use UUIDs

Comment: Aren't UUIDs longer than 5 or 6 characters?

Comment: Yes they are, but it's just out-of-box solution if you want to get unique strings even when generating them on different machines simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be incremented it means you have some transformation function **F()** that transforms from one space to another.

So you probably have a function from {Z} -> {SomeString}

So what you need to do, is just apply the opposite of **F()** (F-1) to the string, get the original number, increment it, and generate it again.

in pseudocode:

```
int i = 1;
String s = Transform(i);
int num = UnTransform(s);
num++;
String next = Transform(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this one:

1. convert the number to binary format;
2. change the order of digits by fixed manual mapping (last digit to 6th place, etc);
3. convert the number back to hash

Comment: Still this and other methods can be guessed easily if knowing enough following number hashes. The best would be rely on hashes with salt and checking the uniqueness if hash small enough to have risk of match.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way to do this would be:

```
$hash_key = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
$hash_table = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J');

$init = 10000000;
$hash_value = str_replace($hash_key, $hash_table, strval($init));

//$hash_value = 'BAAAAAAA'

//For next value:
$init++;
$hash_value = str_replace($hash_key, $hash_table, strval($init));
//$hash_value = 'BAAAAAAB'

//If you want to increment only the string without knowing the digits:
$prev_hash = $hash_value;
$prev_init = intval(str_replace($hash_table, $hash_key, $prev_hash));
//$prev_init = 10000001

$next_init = $prev_init + 1;
$next_hash = str_replace($hash_key, $hash_table, strval($next_init));
//$next_hash = 'BAAAAAAC'
```

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: Sorry, did not notice the Java tag. I'm sure you can find a similar alternative in Java for the algorithm. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions would be to pre-generate the entire dictionary of all possible strings and then use `SecureRandom` to point to an index of that dictionary. If a particular element would already be "reserved", you'd simply go to the next available one (this operation can also be pre-generated btw).

The obvious disadvantage of this solution is non-determinism. But this was not requested by OP. And I'm not even sure if determinism is possible in this situation.

Comment: Assuming the set of strings consists of all alphanumeric (including both upper and lower case) strings of lengths 5 and 6, with each character being one byte in size, that would take up almost 54 gigabytes of space. At a minimum. With only capital letters and digits, though, it brings it down to just over 2 gigabytes.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy method: keep a hashtable or set to store all existing strings, and each time you generate a random string, check to see if it's in the set. If so, generate a new one until you get one that's not in the set.

This would probably be both memory- and processor-intensive in the long run, though.

Answer (score 0):

You might try and convert the following Python to the language of your choice...

```
>>> import string, random, itertools
>>> digits = list(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + '_')
>>> ''.join(digits)
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_'
>>> digit_count = 4
>>> alldigits = [digits[:] for i in range(digit_count)]
>>> for d in alldigits: random.shuffle(d)

>>> numbergen = (''.join(d) for d in itertools.product(*alldigits))
>>> numbergen.__next__()
'B1xx'
>>> numbergen.__next__()
'B1x1'
>>> numbergen.__next__()
'B1xQ'
>>> numbergen.__next__()
'B1x7'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since you want the string to be alphanumeric, then it's pretty straightforward. Create a character array of size 62. This is 26 lowercase letters, 26 uppercase letters, and the 10 digits 0-9. After you fill in the array, loop through N times, where N is the length of your string, selecting a random index each time. So it should look something like this:

```
   char [] arrayOfCharacters = new char[62];
   int index = 0;
   for(char a = 'a';a<= 'z';a++)
   {
           arrayOfCharacters[index++] = a;
   }//copy this loop for the upper case characters and 0-9
   String randomString = "";
   for(int x = 0;x < N; x++)
   {
           randomString += arrayOfCharacters[(int)(Math.random() * arrayOfCharacters.length)];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's my code.. it does exactly what you asked for using the UUID to generate a string then execute (-) from it.

```
import java.util.*;
class KeyGen {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String str = uuid.replaceAll("[-]", "").toUpperCase();
        String s = "";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] array = str.split("");
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int N = rnd.nextInt(str.length());
        System.out.println("How many keys you want?");
        int keys = scan.nextInt();
        String[] rndstr = new String[keys];
        System.out.println("How many letters for the first key?");
        int count = scan.nextInt();
        for (int t = 0; t < keys; t++)
        {
            s="";
            count++; 
            for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                    str = uuid.replaceAll("[-]", "").toUpperCase();
                    int len = str.length();
                    N= rnd.nextInt(len) + 1;
                    s = s + array[N]; 
                }
            rndstr[t] = s;
        }
        for (int j=0; j < rndstr.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(rndstr[j]);
        } 
}
}
```

**Simple output:**

```
How many keys you want?
4
How many letters for the first key?
6

Here are your keys:
5F2934A
C8A456A6
B06E49240
FE3AE40CCE
```

Answer (score -1):

Make your string the result of a hash operation. For example, using your random strings as input:

```
String input1 = "Vg78KY";
String output1 = String.valueOf(input1.hashCode());

String input2 = "Vg78KZ";
String output2 = String.valueOf(input2.hashCode());
```

output1 and output2 will be completely different.

Comment: Yes, of course, great solution. However with such short strings won't there be a collision risk?

Comment: I think it isn't what @richard-h wanted. He wants short alphanumeric hash which won't repeat when incremented and won't be guessable.

Comment: hashCode returns an int, so you're code is wrong and won't return any characters, just numbers.